# Saving Files through Javascript for Local App

Tags: javascript, html, c, linux, web

I am building software that runs locally on web browser. At first I was using C, but it was really hectic with HTML. So I decided to use JavaScript. This requires saving data and saving texts in plain text format. Can I do this with JavaScript? If not, how to integrate it with C or python so that I can save data?

Linux related answers will be helpful.

Comment: Some minimal code example that shows what you try to do (C or JavaScript) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how/where you would like to save the data.

- [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) - A simple key/value store that lives right inside the browser. The data is specific to the computer, browser, and website, but the data persists from session to session with that particular site.
- [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) - Similar to `localStorage`, but the data is removed at the close of the session (when the user leaves your website).
- [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) - if you want to instead store the data on the server, the data can be uniquely identified by a cookie stored in the user's browser. The cookie is sent automatically to the server on each request, that the server interpret and send back the desired data.
- [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) - You could also save your data on the server and implement a RESTful API, and use JavaScript to request the data from the server.

You cannot write to disk directly from JavaScript for obvious security reasons.

Comment: If you are referring to the server-side application, I suppose you could write it in C. There are more modern languages that will help you get a server up and running more quickly, like Java, Scala, Python, Ruby, and others.

Comment: If you are referring to the client-side application (in the browser), your only option is JavaScript. You cannot execute C code from within the browser.

Comment: thanks for replying, I am talking a server-side application. can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I can't speak to how one would implement a server in C, but I would suggest picking up Ruby and learning the Ruby on Rails framework, as it makes bootstrapping web applications quite quick and painless.